# Splitting a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that consists of data with various operators to separate it. I need to split the data according to some requirements.  I am working on a quiz application. I need to display the questions and their options. On *page 1* I need to display a question and its options (based on the number of options that question has, make that many radio buttons dynamically).

Comment: Please take a look in PHP functions explode and implode :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Why should the data be passed via a string? A structure based on array is probably much more efficient.

Comment: hi actaully i need to pass that string to android

Comment: Build the data as an associative array, json_encode it as a string, send it, json_decode it to an array on the other side. As $details already looks like an array, just do `echo json_encode($details);`

Comment: hi actually that server is not supporting json because of lower version...so i am using a string to pass...please suggest me some solution..i am struggling with this

Comment: If you can't upgrade stuff on you server, it's a crappy one - change it.

Comment: If you're passing data from page to page, you don't need to use json or a string. You can use `$_GET` and `$_POST` - that's what they're there for.

Comment: @ASGM - how would you otherwise send a string from one page to another? Are there any other options!

Comment: @adeneo, sorry, I should have been more clear!  I meant that the OP should consider sending each piece of data as separate `$_GET`/`$_POST` variables, rather than going to the trouble to combine them into a single string and then split them on the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While explode would normally suffice, with your multiple delimiters, try preg_split:

```
$chars = preg_split('/@|\|/', 'aaa@bbb|ccc', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($chars);

Array ( [0] => aaa [1] => bbb [2] => ccc )
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a string in PHP:

```
$split = explode('|', $string); // Change '|' for your split case.
$first = $split[0];
$second = $split[1];
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to page1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['finalString'] = $finalstring;
```

add this to the page $finalstring is being passed to:

```
$finalstring = $_SESSION['finalString'];
$array = explode('@', $finalstring);
foreach($array as $item)
{
   echo $item.'<br />';
}

//session_close();
```

hope this helps!